# Interfacting a device's PCM output with a RPi?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, pcm

I am planning to use a SIM7080G for a future project. However, I am facing an issue with the way it handles audio.

The SIM7080G has a PCM interface, which, according to the hardware design guide, is recommended to be used with a NAU88C10. In my project, I would like to have a single speaker/mic used by the entire system. Is there a way, I can get a raspberry pi 4B to interface with this PCM signal so I can use the RPi to handle the audio?

As far as I know, interfacting with the pi's PCM is quite difficult. Therefore, I could use an ADC and DAC after the NAU88C10 does it's job. However, that is an expensive option and also doesn't seem like the best option.

Can anyone suggest a better method?

Thanks